# Creating a directory in linux assembly language

Tags: c, linux, assembly, directory

I am trying to create a small assembly program to create a folder. I looked up the system call for creating a directory on [this page](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-8144.htm). It says that it is identified by 27h. How would I go about implementing the `mkdir somename` in assembly?

I am aware that the program should move 27 into eax but I am unsure where to go next. I have googled quite a bit and no one seems to have posted anthing about this online.

This is my current code (I don't know in which register to put filename and so on):

```
section .data

section .text
global _start

mov eax, 27
mov ????????
....
int 80h
```

Thanks

Comment: Write a simple mkdir example in C first, test it, then disassemble it (gcc -S). This technique works for many "how to" questions about assembler programming.

Comment: Im using NASM by the way.
I tried that but when I disassemble it doesn't call the interrupt for an example.

Comment: That's probably true, but is there a reason you want to use the system call interrupt directly rather than just calling `mkdir`?

Comment: It's probably calling the standard C library for mkdir - is that a problem ?

Comment: Not really a problem but I am trying to see if I can do it directly. Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way of finding out, is using GCC to translate the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main()
{
    if (mkdir("testdir", 0777) != 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

to assembly, with: `gcc mkdir.c -S`

```
    .file   "mkdir.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "testdir"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $511, 4(%esp)
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
    call    mkdir           ; interesting call
    testl   %eax, %eax
    setne   %al
    testb   %al, %al
    je  .L2
    movl    $-1, %eax
    jmp .L3
.L2:
    movl    $0, %eax
.L3:
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Anyway, [ProgrammingGroundUp](http://savannah.c3sl.ufpr.br/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf) page 272 lists important syscalls, including `mkdir`:

```
%eax   Name    %ebx                 %ecx       %edx    Notes
------------------------------------------------------------------
39     mkdir   NULL terminated    Permission           Creates the given
               directory name                          directory. Assumes all 
                                                       directories leading up 
                                                       to it already exist.
```

Comment: call mkdir (into libc) is more portable (as far as one can call assembler such in the first place…) than waving around with int 80, which is practically obsolete with modern hardware.

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers. I will implement it using a call to mkdir instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do like the [Assembly Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) is suggesting. But indeed, calling `mkdir` from Libc is more portable. You need to look into `asm/unistd.h` to get the syscall number.